# With pybind11, how do I set ownership of the underlying memory for an array_t object?

Tags: c++, pybind11

I'm trying to do python embedding in a C++ application with pybind11.

I'm creating an `array_t` with the following function:

```
template<class T>
py::array_t<T> create_matrix(size_t width, size_t height, T* data_ptr = nullptr)
{

    auto b = py::buffer_info(
        data_ptr,
        sizeof(T), //itemsize
        py::format_descriptor<T>::format(),
        2, // ndim
        std::vector<size_t> { width, height }, // shape
        std::vector<size_t> {height * sizeof(T), sizeof(T)} // strides
    );

    return py::array_t<T>(b);
}
```

If I use this function like this:

```
float* raw_array_data = new float[4];

{
    py::array_t<float> arr_f2 = create_matrix<float>(2, 2, raw_array_data);
    ...
}

// Use raw_data_array here.
```

The `raw_array_data` is still available outside of `arr_f2`'s scope.  It appears as though the `array_t` is acting as a 'view' if constructed in this way.

However, in some cases, I may want the `array_t` to take ownership of the memory supplied to `create_matrix`.  How can I tell `array_t` that it owns the memory?

Comment: https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/1042#issuecomment-325941022

Answer (score 0):

If you simply don't pass a data pointer, numpy will allocate the memory for you. If you don't have control over the allocation, you will have to destruct it yourself (As numpy won't know how the data was allocated and there doesn't seem to be a way to pass a deallocator function):

```
{
    // arr_f2 will get numpy to allocate 4 floats
    py::array_t<float> arr_f2 = create_matrix<float>(2, 2);
    ...
}
// and Python will deallocate them when it gets decrefd
```

```
float* raw_array_data = new float[4];

{
    std::unique_ptr<float[]> raw_array_data_destructor(raw_array_data);

    py::array_t<float> arr_f2 = create_matrix<float>(2, 2, raw_array_data);
}
// And std::unique_ptr<float[]>::~unique_ptr will delete[] the data
```

Comment: Thanks.  It seems like using a `unique_ptr` for this would lead to other issues, although it works okay for this particular case.